# Attempt to de-reference a null object error in my apex class

Tags: apex, schema

I got Attempt to de-reference a null object error in my apex class..

We have to execute the fallowing code by schema...

ANY ONE CAN HELP ME REGARDING THIS....

Here is my vf page and apex class..

**VF PAGE:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Project__c" extensions="PlanEditontroller" sidebar="false">
  <apex:form >
        <apex:sectionHeader subtitle="{!ObjPro.Name}" title="{!$Label.pt_Plan}"/>
        <apex:pageBlock title="{!$Label.pt_Edit_plan}" mode="Edit" >
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
                <apex:commandButton value="{!$Label.btn_save}"  action="{!updPlan}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="{!$Label.btn_cancel}" action="{!cancel}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="{!$Label.pt_Edit_plan} {!ObjPro.Name}">
                <apex:inputField value="{!ObjPro.Name}" required="True" label="{!$Label.pt_Plan_name}"/>
                <apex:selectList id="patype" value="{!ObjPro.Plantype__c}"  size="1" multiselect="false" required="true" label="{!$Label.pt_Plantype}">
                   <apex:selectOptions value="{!PLANList}" />
                </apex:selectList>
                <apex:inputField style="width:300px;height:100px;" value="{!ObjPro.Description__c}" label="{!$Label.pt_Description}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!ObjPro.Starts_date__c}" label="{!$Label.pt_Start_date}" />
                <apex:outputText /> 
                <apex:inputField value="{!ObjPro.Ends_date__c}" label="{!$Label.pt_End_date}"/>
                <apex:outputtext />
                <apex:inputField value="{!ObjPro.Status__c}" label="{!$Label.pt_Status}"/>
             </apex:pageBlockSection>   
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

**APEX CLASS:**

```
    public with sharing class PlanEditontroller{
       public List<musqot__Project__c> ObjPro{get;set;}
      //  public musqot__Project__c ObjPro{get;set;}

    List<Project__c > ObjPr {get;set;}
    public Project__c  pln { get; set;}
    Public Id planeId;
    public List<musqot__plantype__c> PLAN_Temp = new List<musqot__plantype__c>();

    //Field Set
    //public List<Schema.FieldSetMember> Fields{get;set;}

    public PlanEditontroller(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

       /*fields = new List<Schema.FieldSetMember>();
       fields =  SObjectType.musqot__Project__c.FieldSets.musqot__Custom_settings.getFields();
       for(Schema.FieldSetMember sf : fields){
           system.debug('------'+sf);*/
       //}


        ObjPro=new  List<Project__c >();
        planeId=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('projectid');

     //   ObjPro=[select id ,Name,Description__c,OwnerId,Starts_date__c,Status__c,Ends_date__c,musqot__Plantype__c from Project__c where id=:planeId ];
        //this.pln = getFieldsetList(planeId);

        /*******************************************************************/

            // Initialize setup variables

            String objectName = 'Project__c';  // modify as needed
            String query = ' SELECT ' ;
            Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> objectFields = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();

            // Grab the fields from the describe method and append them to the queryString one by one.

          for(String s : objectFields.keySet()) {
               query += ' ' + s + ',';
            }

            // Strip off the last comma if it exists.

        if (query.subString(query.Length()-1,query.Length()) == ','){
                query = query.subString(0,query.Length()-1);
            }

            // Add FROM statement

            query += ' FROM ' + objectName + ' WHERE id=:' + planeId ;
            system.debug('******hs___ query '+query);  
            try {
       //      new List<Project__c> ObjPro = database.query(query);
                    ObjPro = database.query(query);
            } catch (QueryException e){
                    //perform exception handling
            }  
     /*******************************************************************/


    }
    public List<SelectOption> PLANList
        {
        get
           {
            PLAN_Temp = [Select u.Name, u.Id From musqot__plantype__c u limit 250];
            PLANList= new List<SelectOption>(); 
            for(musqot__plantype__c objPLA: PLAN_Temp )
            {
            PLANList.add(new SelectOption(objPLA.Id, objPLA.Name));
            }
            return PLANList;
            }
            set;
        }
    public PlanEditontroller(){

    }

  public PageReference updPlan(){
    if (musqot__Project__c.sObjectType.getDescribe().isUpdateable())
      { 
        /*List<Schema.FieldSetMember> tmpList = Fields;
        for(Schema.FieldSetMember sf : tmpList){
            system.debug('******'+sf);
        } */

        update ObjPro;
    }

     Pagereference PR;
     PR = new Pagereference('/apex/ProjectDetails?id='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(planeId,'UTF-8'));                  
     return PR ;

   }

     public PageReference cancel(){
     Pagereference PR;
     PR = new Pagereference('/apex/ProjectDetails?id='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(planeId,'UTF-8'));                  
    return PR ;
    }
     public List<Schema.FieldSetMember> getFields() {
        return SObjectType.musqot__Project__c.FieldSets.musqot__Custom_settings.getFields();
    }

     private Project__c getFieldsetList(String planeId) {


        String query = 'SELECT ';
        for(Schema.FieldSetMember f : this.getFields()) {
            query += f.getFieldPath() + ', ';
        }
        query += 'Id, Name FROM Project__c where id = :planeId order by LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT 1';
        return Database.query(query);
    }

    /*
     public pageReference saveRecord(){

        update ObjPro;
    }*/

}
```

Comment: any one help me how to fix the issue???

Comment: Which line is throwing the error? What have you done to ensure the variable is initialized?

Comment: These types of problems are amenable to either the use of system.debug statements prior to the line throwing the exception or the use of Developer Console Checkpoint feature at the line of code throwing the error. See doc on how to use